# Which conclusion is correct?

Tags: inequality

$P<Q<R=S$ ;
$S ≤ K> M$ ;
$K ≤ L= O > N$

Conclusions:(Please tell me which is correct 1,2 or both or neither)

1. $P<N$
2. $N ≤ P$

Doubt:

I am unable to relate the quantities. I get confused between the subject and predicate while dealing with such problems. Also how do I solve such inequalities to minimize the errors while solving?

Comment: By the way, you should never write inequalities such as $S \le K > M$. When you write $$A \le B < C$$ that literally means "$A \le B$ and $B < C$". But inequalities in the same direction are transitive. Because $A \le B$ and $B < C$, we also know that $A < C$. So "$A \le B < C$" implies to the reader that $A < C$ automatically. But when you mix directions such as with $S \le K > M$, there is no relationship guaranteed between $S$ and $M$. But putting them together in one "combined inequality" suggests a relationship should be there. Better to **never** mix directions in a combined inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, throw out the trash. $Q, R, M, O$ all have single references anywhere in the problem. They serve no purpose than to make the problem more confusing. Because $$A < B < C$$
tells you that $A < C$, if $B$ never comes up again, it serves no purpose. Thus we can reduce the problem to
$$P < S\\S \le K\\ K \le L\\ L > N$$
We can string the first three inequalities together:
$$P < S \le K \le L\\L > N$$
As before, $S, K$ no longer serve a purpose. The first inequality tells us that $P < L$, and $S, K$ do not occur elsewhere in the problem. Also, since all the other inequalities are "$<$" or "$\le$", let's turn around the final inequality between $L$ and $N$:
$$P < L\\N < L$$
So what does that tell us about the relationship between $P$ and $N$? Nothing.
$P$ can be less than $N$, $P$ can be greater than $N$. $P$ can equal $N$. Nothing in the inequalities you gave restricts those options.

Comment: "First, throw out the trash. Q,R,M,O all have single references anywhere in the problem. They serve no purpose than to make the problem more confusing." Please explain this to me.

Comment: These variables are only mentioned once in the entire problem. They have absolutely no impact on the question.